# Nodes - unknown data

Tags: node-editor

I am creating a UV wrap around my doughnut, I go to the shading section to add nodes to create a texture to the doughnut. After I link the noise texture, image texture, texture coordinate and displacement the doughnut turns purple. I have tried finding the missing files, made sure I was in cycles, adding the image to another file, and re-linking all of the nodes and nothing has worked so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your node set up. The described order the nodes does not make sense and would cause an error.